# Find out what code triggered a change in input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, dom-events

I have Chrome auto password filling disabled.

In one particular login page of a website, right after the `load` event, the password input goes from being empty to have a string as its value (not reflected in the DOM). If I take a look through `console.dir()` I can read its value, and is a password I've never use or would use, so I never typed that. Nothing I've searched or asked has been of any help.

I've debugged the page and with an `eventListener` I can pinpoint the exact moment that value is introduced, just listening for the `change` event. But that is not really useful, I just see the input changed with that weird password but know nothing about why it's appearing there. AFAIK the event object doesn't have a clue of who's behind the change.

I want to know **what function or snippet or code is acting on that input** and inserting that useless string.

How can I accomplish that?

**EDIT**: I appreciate the side help but I'm only really interested in the answer to the question asked

Comment: what exactly have you disabled? the Autofill for all forms, or the password management? what is the name of this input? `getAttribute("name")`

Comment: Did you check if it happens on another browser?

Comment: Could you help me understand the relation between those two questions and the thread in hand? Thanks

Comment: The sidehelp is meant to establish whether it's caused by some internal browser function (other than password filling), or something external like an onpage script. If you don't know what it is, at least figure out what it is not... hence the comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the change event you could log a error (`console.error(..)`) which shows the stacktrace.

```js
function iChangedTheValue()
{
   $("#id1").val("value").trigger("change")
}

$("input").on("change", function(event){
  console.error("value of " + event.currentTarget.id + " has been changed")
});


iChangedTheValue();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id1" />
```

In Chrome devtools (<kbd>F12</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's not the magic bullet I was hoping for but it definitely answers my question and helped tracking down the problem :) SO doesn't allow me to give the bounty yet so if I forget feel free to remind me.

Comment: On a side note. You don't have to log an error. You can use console.trace() to get a stack trace.